# How to model bind complex type property of razor page model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an razor page receiving an PageModel descendant.
For exibition-only pages (dashboards, reports, etc), it works like a charm. I use the base PageModel class to make available to turn all pages reflect my hosting.json configuration, making links inside the app dynamic.

**So the hierarchy is: PageModel --> BasePageModel --> ConfigTransmissorFragModel**

Now I have this SendingConfiguration model (I will process it in lower level layer):

```
public class SendingConfiguration
{
    // I will edit this one
    [DisplayName("Send it to production server?")]
    public bool ProductionServer { get; set; }
}
```

The PageModel is as below:

```
// BasePageModel will process the urls of the site.
public class ConfigTransmissorFragModel : BasePageModel
{

    public SendingConfiguration SendConfig { get; set; }

    private void UpdateSendingConfiguration()
    {
        var Config = InfoExibicao.ConfigAtiva;
        ConfigEnvio.ProductionServer = Config.ProductionServer;
    }

    private InfoConfiguration _InfoExibition;
    public InfoConfiguration InfoExibition
    {
        get { return _InfoExibition; }
        set
        {
            _InfoExibition = value;

        }
    }

    public ConfigTransmissorFragModel() : base(null)
    {
        SendConfig = new SendingConfiguration();   
    }

    public ConfigTransmissorFragModel(
        ConfigDashboard PConfigDash,
        InfoConfiguration PInfoConfig
        ) : base(PConfigDash)
    {
        ConfigEnvio = new SendingConfiguration();
        this.InfoExibition = PInfoConfig;
        UpdateSendingConfiguration();
    }
}
```

The Model is generated in controller:

```
var Fch = FacadeInfoConfig;
var InfoConfig = Fch.ObterInfoConfiguracao(IdTransmissor);
var CfgDash = ConfigDash;

var Modelo = new ConfigTransmissorFragModel(CfgDash, InfoConfig);
Modelo.UrlServer = ConfigHost.WebServiceUrl;
```

In the razor page I have this header:

```
@page
@using ESenderWebService.ModeloPagina
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
@using Negocio.Integracao.Configuracao;
@model ESenderWebService.ModeloPagina.ConfigTransmissorFragModel
@{
    //ViewData["Title"] = "Configuracao de Transmissor para envio";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout_Dashboard.cshtml";
}
```

The form:

---

```
    <form autocomplete="off" asp-controller="InfoConfig" asp-action="SalvarConfig" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <fieldset>
                <legend style="width: auto; margin-bottom: auto;"> Configurações </legend>
                            <div>
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SendConfig.ProductionServer)
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SendConfig.ProductionServer)
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
                            </div>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
```

---

My problem is: how to receive SendingConfiguration on my post handler?

```
    // This one explodes complaining that HttpContext is missing  
    [HttpPost()]
    public IActionResult SalvarConfig(ConfigTransmissorFragModel PModel)


    // This one never reflects what I mark in the form
    // It always returns false in PModel.ProductionServer
    [HttpPost()]
    public IActionResult SalvarConfig([FromForm] SendingConfiguration PModel)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try using [FromBody] instead of [FromForm]

Comment: @sam HTTP ERROR 415 Doesn't even enter on the handler.

Comment: Did you have spell mistake ? It should be `SendingConfiguration` not `SendindConfiguration ` ?

Comment: @NanYu it was a typo. I've translated the names from Portuguese to English, so I ended with a few typos. Hope this is the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the first HttpPost syntax exploding in your case, because its working fine in my sample project.

[image]

Comment: BasePageModel is descended from PageModel, you have descended you model from PageModel? I've updated the text.

Comment: When I posted that screenshot, it was not. But it still works even after adding PageModel as base class. Mine is Core 2.1.